# Error connecting to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a small problem. I am trying to perform a simple operation but I keep on getting the same error, I am running out of ideas and I couldn't find anything in the internet...

The portion of code causing the error is the following:

```
response.write(readDB(no));   // <= this line
response.end();
```

The readDB function is here:

```
function readDB(gene){
    console.log("test43");
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
    console.log("test44");
    var collection = db.collection('links');
    var ans=  collection.find( { generated: gene}, {original:1, _id:0}, function(err, gg){
    console.log("test dat result:"+ans.original);
        console.log("acces to:"+ans.original);
        var rep
        rep.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        rep.write("<html>");
        rep.write("<head>");
        rep.write("<title>Redirection</title>");
        rep.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5\"; URL=\""+ans.original+"\">");
        rep.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.href = \""+ans.original+"\"</script>");
        rep.write("</head>");
        rep.write("<body>Redirection...");
        rep.write("</body>");
        rep.write("</html>");
        return rep;
  })
  }
  if(err){
    //console.log(err)
  }
  } )};
```

I know the code is not great, but still...
The message "test43" is shown in my console, and after that I keep getting:

```
_http_outgoing.js:436
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
```

If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong it would be great !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that `response.write()` is expecting a `string` (or `Buffer`), but your function `readDB` does not return anything there is a callback inside of this function that returns something but this is asynchronously called so your erring line is being read as `response.write(undefined)`.  Perhaps consider passing the `response` object as an argument by changing your `readDB` function to look like this:

```
function readDB(gene, rep){
...
}
```

then call it like this:

```
readDB(no, response);   // <= this line
```

You will also need to remove the `var rep` inside your function as it will overwrite the passed in response argument (also returning it will not be necessary though there is no side effect that I can think of by unnecessarily returning it). Finally you will want to not call `response.end()` right after calling your updated `readDB` function because the output generated by the callback will not have had time to execute.

Comment: I made your corrections and it works ! Thank you very much ! However I have now another problem, the execution returns:
`test42
test43
We are connected
test44
/home/ubuntu/workspace/UShort/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'original' of undefined
`

I guess it didn't have time to retrieve data from the database and returned undefined...

Do you have any solution for this ?

Thanks again

Comment: It might be tempting to append to your original post, but I would strongly encourage you to post your new problem as a new question as it will have the greatest likelihood of attracting a good answer

Comment: Yeah, but I guess it would be better to avoid to spam it since it's not very important ...

Comment: Well actually the problem you are running into is related to your original misunderstanding, you are trying to read the return value of `collection.find()` when in fact `find` is also asynchronous, the result of `find()` is passed as the second argument to the callback you passed to it (`gg` in your code).